# Is there a way to stop listening to an event when some condition is met using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking all over for this, can't find anything. I'm just making a last ditch effort to see if this is possible or not.
I just want to quit listening to an event if a condition is met like

```js
if (condition) // stop event
```

Just let me know if this is possible or not and we'll be on our way.
And yes I have just tried using `return` but it will keep listening.

Comment: You can remove listener when condition is met. Please look into `removeEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use "removeEventListener".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener